# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 4) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am doing classification on 4 classes but When I tried to run this:

```
IMG_SIZE = 50    
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 256, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 4, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

train = train_data[:-810]
test = train_data[-810:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True)
```

It's giving me error that

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 4) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

But I am not getting where (64,4) and (?,2) is this coming from? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have written regression in line 16?

Comment: That is not the problem I suppose. Please elaborate and where these shapes are coming from? @heenabawa

Comment: `(64, 4)` is supposed to be the shape of each target sample, e.g. `Y[0]`; and `(?, 2)` is supposed to be the shape of the output of `regression(...)`, but if the last fc has 4 outputs, then this code cannot throw such `ValueError` (assuming you're not using a custom `regression` implementation).

Comment: pls provide more info about your dataset like dims of `X`, `Y` and test.

Comment: shape of train is (3233, 2) i.e.(number of examples, image array along with its label)

Comment: @Percy your last fc should be 2 and not 4, then

Comment: When the shape of train is (3233, 2), I think that ValueError will be displayed at line 23. What is the shape of X and Y?